# Spring Security password encoder requiring bean even though it's already in the configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, annotations

I'm making a authentication method to secure my API with Spring Security and JWT. I'm using a password encoder for a register method to secure the user. I have declare a bean for it but I'm getting an error saying:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.akuntansi.akuntansi.repo.AuthenticationService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' in your configuration.
```

Here's my config that got all the bean:
:

```
package com.akuntansi.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import com.akuntansi.akuntansi.repo.UserRepo;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AppConfig {

    private final UserRepo userRepo;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
        return username -> userRepo.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found!"));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }
    
    @Bean
     public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception{
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```

And here's the `AuthenticationService.java`:

```
package com.akuntansi.akuntansi.repo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.akuntansi.akuntansi.model.Role;
import com.akuntansi.akuntansi.model.Users;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationService {
    
private final UserRepo userRepo;
private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
private final JWTService jwtService;
private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public AuthenticationResponse register(RegisterRequest request){
        var user =  Users.builder()
                    .username(request.getUsername())
                    .password(passwordEncoder.encode(request.getPassword()))
                    .role(Role.USER)
                    .build();
                    
        userRepo.save(user);
        var jwtToken = jwtService.generateJwtToken(user);

        return AuthenticationResponse.builder()
                .token(jwtToken) 
                .build();
    }

    public AuthenticationResponse login(AuthenticationRequest request){
        authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                request.getUsername(),
                request.getPassword()
            )
        );
        var user = userRepo.findByUsername(request.getUsername()).orElseThrow();
        var jwtToken = jwtService.generateJwtToken(user);
        return AuthenticationResponse.builder()
                .token(jwtToken)
                .build();
    }
}
```

I have no idea what's wrong since as you can see, I already made a bean type for it.

Comment: Where is your Spring Boot package class? Is it in the package `com.akuntansi`? Or is it in a sub package?

Comment: Yes it's in the `com.akuntansi` package